# Detect real IP address when machine has several network cards

Tags: python, sockets

I tried using this command:

```py
name = socket.gethostname()
address_info = socket.gethostbyname(name)
```

But this returns IP address `169.x.x.x` instead of my real address `(192.168.x.x`), and thats because my machine has several `network` cards.

How to detect my real IP address?

Comment: Are you open to use `netifaces` ?

Comment: What do you mean ? i just want to solve it

Comment: Please try the code snippet on my most recent edit, it's pretty for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [netifaces](https://alastairs-place.net/projects/netifaces/). it'll make your task simpler

```
import netifaces
netifaces.interfaces()
```

Output would be list of all interfaced

```
['lo0', 'gif0', 'stf0', 'en0', 'en1', 'fw0']
```

You can dig into it further like so -

```
netifaces.ifaddresses('en0')
```

Output would be-

```
{18: [{'addr': '00:12:34:56:78:9a'}], 2: [{'broadcast':
 '10.255.255.255', 'netmask': '255.0.0.0', 'addr': '10.16.1.4'}],
 30: [{'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::', 'addr':
 'fe80::123:4567:89ab:cdef%en0'}]}
```

find interface address

```
netifaces.ifaddresses('en0')[netifaces.AF_LINK]
```

Output

```
[{'addr': '00:12:34:56:78:9a'}]
```

You can loop through all the interface and retrieve IP Address like so-

```
for interface in netifaces.interfaces():
...   for link in netifaces.ifaddresses(interface)[netifaces.AF_INET]:
...     print link['addr']
```

Comment: But how can i automatically determine what the ip address that connected to the internet ? (my list is with 4 different addresses)

Comment: And i want only the IPv4 addresses

Answer (score 1):

You can use the netifaces package: [Doc](https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/)

There is a confusion about what you mean as "real" address, all the network interfaces are entitled to one or more IP addresses and they are real.

However, if you mean to select a particular IP address that is connecting you to the internet or such then you can pretty pick the interface and fetch it's primary IP address.

Maybe this code will be of help:

```
import netifaces

def main():
    for item in netifaces.interfaces():
        print(netifaces.ifaddresses(item))
        print("\n")

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

If you want to know your external network facing interface, use the following code:

```
print(netifaces.gateways()['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][0])
```

Comment: it doesn't need to, in all likelihood OP is behind a NAT and using a private IP address; the question doesn't ask about the public IP of the environment either.

Comment: And after i have this getway how can i get the ip address that represent this getway ?

Comment: please run the last snippet, it's printing out the IP address of your default gateway. Can you share what you see?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can fix the problem this way.

```py
import socket

def my_ip():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        s.connect(('stackoverflow.com', 1027))
    except socket.error:
        return None
    return s.getsockname()[0]
```

Comment: And if i want to get the internal ip address ?

Comment: I'm sorry I got the question wrong. I understanded the actual IP address as an external IP address. I hope my answer edited will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
from pyroute2 import IPRoute

with IPRoute() as ipr:
    op = ipr.route('get', dst='8.8.8.8') #Find route to the google dns server
    for tup in op[0]['attrs']:
        if tup[0] == 'RTA_PREFSRC': # Preferred source address will be your ip address
            print(tup[1])
```

Comment: i installed pyroute2  but i have this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win_inet_pton'